# Is MySQL more efficient than a file system?

Tags: mysql, database

In a game with a client-server database management system, would it be more efficient to have this data stored with something like MySQL or would a file system with everything being saved and stored in the server files, considering that this will be intended for thousands of accounts to be created.

Comment: This is entirely too broad and vague. Clearly which is *more efficient* will depend entirely on the actual data being stored, the database schema in use, the indexes that exist, and the specific file system being considered. If you're not happy with what you have, do your own benchmarking with your actual data and determine if the alternative would better suit your needs. There is no *one size fits all* answer to which would be more efficient.

Comment: There is also a middle way: SQLite

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement. If I were you I would have prefer [REDIS](http://redis.io) which is a deal breaker for real time database

The following  can be your use case

```
Real-time publish/subscribe notification systems(You can publish your highest score)
Real-time analytics backends
Task queues and job systems(Some time you have to run some background jobs)
High score leaderboards
User ranking systems
```